# Error creating bean with name 'XXX: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XXX'

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below is the trace :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'testDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testDAO': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed
>   type: class modele.Test

...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'testDAO': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class modele.Test

...

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
>   class modele.Test

From my understanding the root error is `Not a managed type: class modele.Test`, which would have something to do with Test not being recognized as an entity ?

Here's my project :

Architecture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcYVi.jpg

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("boot")
@ComponentScan("dao")
@ComponentScan("modele")
@EnableJpaRepositories("dao")
public class Application {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**TestDAO.java**

```
@Transactional
public interface TestDAO extends CrudRepository<Test, Long > {

  /**
   * This method will find an User instance in the database by its email.
   * Note that this method is not implemented and its working code will be
   * automagically generated from its signature by Spring Data JPA.
   */
  public Test findByEmail(String email);

}
```

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    // An autogenerated id (unique for each user in the db)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // Public methods

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Test(String email, String name) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
    }
//setters and getters
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, those 4 last annotations are useless if you put your application in a parent package of "dao",  "modele" and "boot". Spring Boot will automatically apply sensible defaults based on that.

Comment: Yes but that was not the case in my code. I now have changed that though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With your current setup, you need to add**

```
@EntityScan("modele")
```

`Test` isn't really a Spring Bean per say, it's a *JPA Entity*. `@ComponentScan` looks for `@Configuration`, `@Component`, `@Service` and `@Repository`, `@Controller` and `@RestController`. `@EntityScan` will look for Entities.

You can read this: [Difference between @EntityScan and @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896414/difference-between-entityscan-and-componentscan)

> **Your configuration would be much easier if you'd move :**

- Application.java at the root of your packages: `com.domain.project`;
- your repositories under `com.domain.project.dao`;
- your entities under `com.domain.project.domain`.

Then, you wouldn't need `@EntityScan`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`, SpringBoot will just pickup everything found in  com.domain.project.*

Comment: Thank you, modified the architecture as you explained at it is working.